# Java Mongodb regex query

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

I have to run this query in Java

```
 db.Users.find({"name": /^ind/i})
```

My Java code is

```
Document findQuery = new Document();
findQuery.append("name", Pattern.compile("/^"+name+"/i"));
FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("Users").find(findQuery);
```

It is not returning any data, I think the above java code is converting

```
> /^ind/i into "/^ind/i"
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Based on stribizhev suggestion updated the query and its worked

```
db.Users.find({"name": {"$regex": /^ind/, "$options": "i"}})
```

Java code

```
Document regQuery = new Document();
regQuery.append("$regex", "^(?)" + Pattern.quote(name));
regQuery.append("$options", "i");

Document findQuery = new Document();
findQuery.append("name", regQuery);
FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("Users").find(findQuery);
```

Comment: In Java, do not use regex delimiters. Try `"^(?i)"+Pattern.quote(name)` instead of `"/^"+name+"/i"`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked so basically "^(?)"+Pattern.quote("ind") converted value to ^(?)\Qind\E

Comment: Yes, that is true. I posted the suggestion as an answer.

Comment: Please specify which import you use.
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

Comment: Something similar worked for me - `findQuery.append("name", new BsonRegularExpression(regexLiteral));`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use regex delimiters in Java `Pattern.compile`, as there are other means in Java (e.g. flags) to do the same.

To enforce case-insensitive search, use inline modifier `(?i)`. So,
use `"^(?i)"+Pattern.quote(name)` instead of `"/^"+name+"/i"`.

`Pattern.quote` just escapes all regex metacharacters so  that they were treated as literals (same as `\Q`...`\E`).

Comment: Yes, exactly so I updated the mongo query as well to use this
db.Users.find({"name": {"$regex": /^ind/, "$options": "i"}})
Java code is 
Document regQuery = new Document();
    regQuery.append("$regex", "^(?)" + Pattern.quote(name));
    regQuery.append("$options", "i");

Comment: You may add this code you end up with to the question, at the end.

Answer (score 8):

I guess there is a more elegant way to do that in Java, by using the provided Filters in the MongoDB Java Driver (version 3 and above):

```
Document query = new Document("equipment","gloves");

//whatever pattern you need. But you do not need the "/" delimiters
String pattern = ".*" + query.getString("equipment") + ".*";

//find(regex("field name", "pattern", "options"));
collection.find(regex("equipment", pattern, "i"));
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use Pattern -and Filters-

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("ind", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Bson filter = Filters.eq("name", regex);
```

The object Pattern has some other flags, as you can see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#field_summary)

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers here are not working for me (maybe not up-to-date MongoDB Java driver). Here is what worked for me:

```
Document regexQuery = new Document();
regexQuery.append("$regex", ".*" + Pattern.quote(searchTerm) + ".*");
BasicDBObject criteria = new BasicDBObject("name", regexQuery);
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(criteria);
```